# Move data/images between two iOS apps using custom URL handler

Tags: ios, uiimage, nsdata, data-transfer

After googling around and searching SO for a while, I stil couldn't find an answer -

I've wondered, How could I transfer data between two of my apps using custom URL handlers? Specifically images or an NSData object for that matter.

I know about being able to open specific parts of my app using custom handlers such as myapp1://start , myapp2://start , but I'm not sure how to go on transferring large amounts of data (~80k) through these handlers.

Would love to hear any creative solutions :)

**p.s.** The solution should be iOS >= 4.3 Compatible

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the custom URL handlers in combination with UIPasteboard.  Save something from your first app (say, an image) to the general pasteboard, like so:

```
UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
[[UIPasteboard generalPasteboard] setImage:myImage];
```

Then use the custom URL schemes to switch apps.

Then retrieve your image from within the new app when you need it:

```
   UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
   UIImage *tempImg = pasteboard.image;
```

Battle-tested.  ; )

Answer (score 3):

One Solution could be:

- Implement a Webserver
- Open up your second app via the custom url scheme with the IP-adress and the port of your custom web server included in the url
- Add the route or parameters to your image also to your URL

Download and enjoy your photo :-)

Another Solution:

- Start a Bonjour service
- in a network the second app can find this service
- do some magic to pass the data in between the apps

EDIT:
BETTER OTHER SOLUTION:

Just found another, but much more efficient way to do exchanges of larger data sets:
It is called `UIPasteboard`

Best reference for that:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPasteboard_Class/Reference.html

And another resource:
http://kmithi.blogspot.in/2012/03/sharing-data-among-ios-applications.html

That should do it. 
For a webserver: There are tons of implementations found using Google

Comment: Could provide any documentation or samples to point me in the right direction?

Comment: implementing Webserver will consume resources useless. Others solutions needs networking.

Comment: Hey @matheszabi. You shouldn't down vote, just because the solution consumes resources. And if you down voted me, just because I downvoted you: YOUR SOLUTION IS NOT ALLOWED AND NOT WORKING

Comment: Implementing a short webserver or a bonjour service might work but please provide more info on HOW and not just WHAT. Thank you.

Comment: @ShaiMishali Made my EDIT, please check it out and use UIPasteboard

Comment: Your answer was correct but not very informative when compared to crgt. So im marking his as the most correct one and will give you the bounty.

Comment: Yes, that's very ok for me. Thank you. Enjoy the solution!

Answer (score 1):

```
     [http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43447/How-to-Use-UIPasteBoard-to-Implement-Custom-Copy-a][1]

        As you know many of the controls in UIKit now come pre-loaded with the ability to copy and paste text. You can also use this new ability in your own apps to copy and paste other things including: images, SQLite databases, text or any file. This is a great way to share data between your apps if you want to provide users with a suite of apps with integrated functionality.



     CopyFrom Source Code
        -(IBAction)copyImageToPasteBoard{
            UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyFrom" 
                     create:YES];
            appPasteBoard.persistent = YES;

            NSData *data = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"Old-Time-Photo.jpg"]);
            [appPasteBoard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"com.appshop.copyfrom.imagedata"];
        }

        -(IBAction)copyStringToPasteBoard{
            UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyFrom" 
                     create:YES];
            appPasteBoard.persistent = YES;
            [appPasteBoard setString:textView.text];
        }
        PasteTo Source Code
        -(IBAction)pasteImageToPasteBoard{
            UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyFrom"
                     create:YES];
            NSData *data = [appPasteBoard dataForPasteboardType:@"com.appshop.copyfrom.imagedata"];
            imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
        }

        -(IBAction)pasteStringToPasteBoard{
            UIPasteboard *appPasteBoard = [UIPasteboard pasteboardWithName:@"CopyFrom" 
                     create:YES];
            textView.text = [appPasteBoard string];
        }


    Using UIPasteBoard in iPhone programming is amazingly simple and opens up some possibilities that we did not have a year ago. To use UIPasteBoard you simply create a instance using pasteboardWithName, put stuff into the paste board and then set the persistant property equal to YES. Then any app can get a reference to your paste board and use the data contained within. You can use it for simple strings and even data that you can put into NSData like SQLite databases.
```

Answer (score 0):

> using custom URL handler

it is specified, so it will not meet your specification.

But if you don't care about that, I would write to internal memory (file system)the 80k image, even if 80Mb and pass the "url" for the other app.

Big ego, and 0 effort in research:

[copy to images folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178915/how-to-save-picture-to-iphone-photo-library)

[IPC communication via url](http://www.screencast.com/users/millenomi/folders/Default/media/795720b0-cf1c-4c96-b063-7498f0c4bc77)

and my solution doesn't work... I am not giving fish, just teaching hot to get a fish.

Comment: How would I write the data as a resource accessible by both apps ? Isn't each app sandboxed ?

Comment: how to do it that is another question, but here is a post about that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500935/does-iphone-api-allow-application-read-write-to-iphones-filesystem , pls check the second answer

Comment: Apps are indeed sandboxed. Not possible to access the files of another app (speaking of no jailbreak)

Comment: there are common part where each of they can acces, like I have provided the link too, pls check it

Comment: @matheszabi second answer's link isn't working. And you cannot share files between apps, as you write them to disk. They are contained in a secure container. NO JAILBREAK

Comment: @matheszabi - The link you provided makes it seem like its not possible. You can't access it without a jailbreak. Of course the solution has to be App-Store approvable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, as far as I can tell ~80k is too much for a custom URL handler. But you could try to Base64-encode your data and append it to the custom URL. But I doubt that it will work with lots of data.

You could also have a look on the `UIDocumentInteractionController`, which is intended to open files with other applications that support them. This is what the Mail application does when you open an attachment with another app.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304

Comment: Doesnt help me since it opens a dialog. It needs to be seamless. thanks anyways.

Comment: I don't know the limitation but 100mo is ok with URL Scheme using Base64 encode