# iOS8: Frameworks -- In storyboard referencing images from the App

Tags: ios, ios8, storyboard, ios-frameworks

I'm thinking about doing a `Framework` to share code between two apps.  I would like to include a `Storyboard` with a `View Controller` that will reference an image inside the App.

For example:  In the `Framework`, the `UIImageView` in the View Controller will reference an image called "Car", however, the image will not be included in the `Framework`.  The App consuming the `Framework` will provide Car.PNG

**Question 1:**  Is this possible?

**Question 2:**  Can I reference the image in Storyboard Interface Builder under attribute inspector? or do I have to do it in code?

**Question 3:**  Do I need to do anything special, i.e. provide the bundle or anything?

Comment: Not sure, but are you saying that you want to have to separate apps in the app store, and share content with each other? Maybe this will give you a feeling of how it might be done: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12276827/move-data-images-between-two-ios-apps-using-custom-url-handler

Comment: Thanks.  No, I would like to create frameworks that manage the common files between apps.  I'm trying to avoid having duplicate code in apps.

Comment: Hey @user1107173 , have you found any solution so far? The one I have now is to go full throttle and reload images in code - that will work. (imageNamed: is looking into app's assets).